# Google Script, switch to Legacy editor failure

Tags: google-apps-script

[![][1]][1]

Hi! When switched to legacy editor this screen showed up and it makes impossible to switch back to new version as inactive button. I did sign off and sign in, it does not help. Any ideas how to get back to new editor?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz7Rp.png

Comment: Everything works as expected for me; have you tried refreshing the script page? Or create a new one?

Comment: Yes, did not work out

Comment: Have you tried using another browser?

Comment: I tried to use different google account and it worked out but its not what I'm looking for. I would need to restore switch to new editor

Answer (score 0):

**What you are describing might in fact be a bug.**

You may want to check this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181968397) on Google's Issue Tracker.

I suggest you star the issue here and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it.